# Content types understood by an application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, content-type

Given an application path (or `NSBundle` to an application, etc), is there a way to easily/efficiently determine what content types that application can open?

My initial attempt was to read the application's Info.plist file and extract the content types listed under the `kUTExportedTypeDeclarationsKey` key.  However, there are some flaws with this approach which I haven't been able to work around.

1. Not all applications use this key.  For example, BBEdit does not, but instead lists a whole bunch of recognized file extensions.
2. UTIs are case-sensitive.  Pages, for example, lists `com.apple.iWork.Pages.pages` as an exported content type, yet no Pages document actually has that type listed in its content type tree.  Documents use `com.apple.iwork.pages.pages`, which is defined by the iWork quicklook generator (at `/Library/QuickLook/iWork.qlgenerator`).

In know that with some of the LaunchServices functions (`LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL()`, `LSCopyApplicationForMIMEType()`, etc), I can get the applications that can open a file (or a file type), but I'd like to do the inverse. (Perhaps I'll have to resort to parsing the output of `lsregister -dump`?)

Perhaps a simpler way to phrase the question would be:  Given an application, what's the easiest way to find all files that it can open?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at LaunchServices and the provided [LSCanRefAcceptItem()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2F%23documentation%2FCarbon%2FReference%2FLaunchServicesReference%2FReference%2Freference.html&rct=j&q=lscanrefacceptitem&ei=HKenTZGdG86O0QGjn_35CA&usg=AFQjCNEL6_EXLwjPTgWUPgZdI08Ik1xvmg) API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems using the LSItemContentTypes key is the preferred method post-10.4.

[Apple: Document-Based Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html)

Comment: To be clearer, LSItemContentTypes is not a top-level key, it is used within the CFBundleDocumentTypes array.